# parallel ajax calls - behavior like multithreaded system

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a java code that processes a csv file 1 line at a time. I want to update the user with the record being currently processed like (1 of 1000 completed, 3 of 1000 completed and so on). This is a piece of code i have written so far. The first call is the PROCESS FILE and second call with a repetition of 3 seconds is the GET CURRENT RECORD.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/service_member_import.jsp",
        aysnc: false,
        data: {
             "action":"processrecords",
             "ms": new Date().getTime()
         },   
         dataType : 'html',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("file processed");
        },
     error: function(){
            alert("Error retrieving data");
        }
    });

setInterval(update, 3000);
update();

function update() {
      $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "service_member_import.jsp",
            data: {
                 "action":"getStatus",
                 "ms": new Date().getTime()
             },   
            dataType : 'html',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("current data\t");
                console.log(data);
            },
         error: function(){
                alert("Error retrieving data");
            }
        });

}
```

The current behavior is that it processes all the records (ie 1st ajax call) and then gives me the current record processed (ie 2nd ajax call). ie both ajax calls are not taking place parallel.

Please suggest me if you think there are better ways to achieve this. Or if we can make these ajax calls parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the two ajax calls were being made parralely. It was just that the number of records were too less hence the first ajax call finished almost immediately and gave a feeling that the second ajax call was only made at the end.

As soon as i increased the records to 30,000. I could see that second ajax call did interrupt in between the first ajax call.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your webserver is blocking the second request until the first one is finished...

You need a non-blocking or threaded server for this to work.

What platform are you using?(Ruby/Rails, Node/Sails, PHP/Cake, Python/Django etc.)

Comment: its bootstrap for front end + java at backend. for interaction its jquery. I am not using node/ php or anything. If you suggest me node.js could you tell me how will my java code integrate with node.js ? I have been trying to work on node.js since yesterday and finally gave up with using 2 ajax calls.

Comment: I just realized you mentioned Java. Well, it appears that your Java server is running in a single threaded/blocking way. I'm not familiar with Java servers, sorry. As for Node.js, it doesn't "directly" integrate with Java at all. Java and JavaScript are not even close to the same thing. But I do think Node.js would be a good choice for what your doing. If you want to get started with Node.js, check out [Sails!](http://sailsjs.org)

Comment: Yes i have written the processing code + validation + database code in java. So its just one call to my java method . But now with this call i want to even update the user with the current record being processed. Also, if i use node.js ill have to convert my java code to js ?

Comment: Yep, you would have to convert it all....I would probably see if there was a way to run my server in threaded mode. I'm guessing you are using webring or jetty. Check the docs....

Comment: yes but even if i run the server in multithreaded mode how will i collect the replies bcoz the ajax calls are single threaded.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, but asynchronous/non-blocking. You have to allow your ajax calls to run asynchronously. Remove the `async: false`

Comment: ajax calls are asynchronous - `$.ajax(...)` returns immediately without waiting for the server response. You can execute `update();` without waiting for ajax response to come back. But if the server does not return until it finishes processing, all subsequent ajax requests will be waiting on the server - this is done to protect the  Session. Find out if there is a way to mark server-side request handlers as session-read-only.